# Javascript for every image

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I want to do something for every div witch class starts with obj_
For example:

```
<img class="obj_1" />
```

i want to resize every image to the scale size for example:

```
scale = 2
```

then i want to double the image width and height.
I want also do this with the position left and top.
The image will be loaded like:

```
<div id='obj' class="obj_84" style='top:1152px;left:6px;' onmousedown='return false;'><img src ="img/obj/0.png" /></div>
```

How can i do this?
I'l hope you have enough information to solve my question.

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please consider improving your question. Your question in its current form does not contain enough details. Please read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) and the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) section on ways to improve your question. For example, are you using a framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('div[class^=obj_] img').each( function( ){
   $(this).css({
     width: $(this).width() * 2,
     height: $(this).height() * 2

   });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

For simplicity's sake I'd recommend using the [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) JavaScript library. The following [jQuery selector](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) will select all divs that start with obj_:

```
$('div[class^="obj_"]')
```

Comment: I've changed my explaination a bit

Comment: Well, it looks like you haven't just changed your explanation a bit but rather posted a completely new and different question. What have you tried? Why didn't it work?

Comment: Sorry ;) can you help me out?

Comment: Yeah it works but i need to change the position from top to like topnow / scale

Answer (score 0):

You can use JQuery for this. Here is an examples:

http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/

http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-prefix-selector/

Answer (score 0):

hi you will have to use the follwing script to to select your each img tag which starts with 'obj_'

```
$('img[class^="obj_"]');
```

once you find the selector use each function and of jQuery to resize each of your images on the document. jQuery has width and height properties available for the object you select.

Hope you understand logic and try to implement it. in case you have any problem in building the logic you can revert we are here to help you...